# Where can I find a good list of MLA citation formats?

Tags: citation, mla

I am working on programing a citation generator. It will only make citations in MLA format.

Does anyone know where I can find a good MLA citation form resource

Comment: Purdue University provides an online [MLA Formatting and Style Guide](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/01/). If by citation form resource you are asking for software recommendations, you are on the wrong site.

Comment: @choster I am doing the programming myself, I don't need help with the coding. I just need to figure out the MLA citation formats.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for resources.

Comment: This question might be better asked at writers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Library.Cornell.edu](http://www.library.cornell.edu/resrch/citmanage/mla) has a substantial amount of different types of citations along with examples, all on a single webpage.

[Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/05/) also several different MLA citations for various source formats, but they are separated across multiple pages.

Comment: Plus one for citing my *alma mater*, Cornell.  Seriously, that is rather helpful even if the question is off-topic.